# How to XOR n same numbers?

Tags: java, xor, boolean-operations

I want to XOR number k with itself n time. Easiest way is to XOR it with itself n time in a loop. Is there a better way?

```
int t = k;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) k = k ^ t;
```

Comment: `(n % 2 == 1) ? k : 0`.

Comment: Wait, your code doesn't match your English. You say you want to XOR k with itself, but your code XORs it with other numbers.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: `int 0 = 1;` - did you mean `int i`?

Comment: @user2357112 probably.

Comment: Can somebody just tell if there is a better way to implement the 2 line of code i typed :|

Comment: @JuBc there's one in the answers below.

Comment: @JuBc, kindly have a look at my solution too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XORing N copies of K together produces K if N is odd and 0 if N is even. K ^ K == 0, 0 ^ K == K, and it just alternates between those results with every additional K. (Your code is currently XORing n+1 copies of k together, which I'm guessing is a mistake.)

```
int result = (n % 2 == 1) ? k : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even number of `XOR's` of a number result in 0 : `k ^ k = 0`
Odd number of `XOR's` of a number result in that number:   `k ^ k ^ k = k`

Thus, you need not `XOR the number` with itself `n` number of times to check the final result.
In fact, you don't have to XOR at all. Just check whether `n` is even or odd.

```
return (n & 1) == 0 ? 0 : k
```

When even `(n & 1) = 0` | When odd `(n & 1) = 1`